# TYPO3 extension: Why do i need the notation in this comments block?

Tags: typo3

Within my TYPO3 extension in my controllers: What does the following code do or rather "Why do i need the notation in the comments block?".

```
 /**
  * action show
  *
  * @param \Cjk\Icingaconfgen\Domain\Model\Appliance $appliance
  * @return void
  */
public function showAction(\Cjk\Icingaconfgen\Domain\Model\Appliance $appliance)
    {
        $this->view->assign('appliance', $appliance);
    }
```

I've already defined the parameter in the function, so why the comments block? I know it's necessary, but i never understood this concept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The annotations in the doc-block determine how the PropertyMapper is mapping the incoming POST or GET data into proper objects. As Mathias Brodala said in his answer, you don't need them per se, if you have type hints for your parameters, but there is a little exception to this. If your action expects an ObjectStorage, you might want to hint the type of the contents of that ObjectStorage. Otherwise, the PropertyMapper can't convert the incoming data properly. For example:

```
/**
 * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<\VENDOR\Extension\Domain\Model\SomeModel> $someModelStorage
 */
public function indexAction(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage $someModelStorage){
    // do something
}
```

This example code will fail, because of the type-hint. This is because extbase ignores the `@var` annotation, if a type-hint is present.
You need to remove the type-hint and must provide the `@var` annotation for the PropertyMapper to have the right information on how to map incoming data properly. So for the above example to work properly, you must write it this way:

```
/**
 * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<\VENDOR\Extension\Domain\Model\SomeModel> $someModelStorage
 */
public function indexAction($someModelStorage){
    // do something
}
```

Anyway, doc-comments are useful for documenting functionality and you should write them, to provide additional information about your functions for other developers or even your future self ;)

Answer (score 2):

For controller actions the docblock is in fact not necessary. Extbase determines the type of action arguments from the method signature. But there are features like validation which *must* be defined in the action docblock.

That said it is generally a good practice to add docblocks with full annotations for every single method throughout the codebase.